# Angular2 Routing: what does it mean that it creates an instance of the component associated?

Tags: angular

I'm teaching myself Angular2 and the text I'm looking at says:

> The router locates or creates an instance of the component associated with the route, and that component’s view is displayed in the location defined by the RouterOutlet directive.

The code example:

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
import {ProductListComponent} from './products/product-list.component';
import {ProductService} from './products/product.service';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS, RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';
import 'rxjs/Rx'; //Load all features
import {WelcomeComponent} from './home/welcome.component'
@Component({
    selector: 'pm-app',
    template:`
    <div>
        <nav class='navbar navbar-default'>
            <div class='container-fluid'>
                <a class='navbar-brand'>{{pageTitle}}</a>
                <ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
                    <li><a [routerLink]="['Welcome']">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a [routerLink]="['Products']">Product List</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class='container'>
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </div>`,
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [ProductService, HTTP_PROVIDERS, ROUTER_PROVIDERS]
})
@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/welcome', name: 'Welcome', component: WelcomeComponent, useAsDefault: true },
    {path: '/products', name: 'Products', component: ProductListComponent}
])
export class AppComponent {
    pageTitle: string = "Acme Product Management";
}
```

The question is: I can see the locate part but what does it mean that it creates an instance of the component associated? Does it just {} and if so what will display in the associated RouterOutlet directive?

Answer (score 1):

You have RouteConfig annotation which consist from two config objects:

```
{path: '/welcome', name: 'Welcome', component: WelcomeComponent, useAsDefault: true },
{path: '/products', name: 'Products', component: ProductListComponent}
```

Each of this object has it's own path `/welcome` and associated component `WelcomeComponent`, for instance.

If you are going to `/welcome` location, angular put associated to this path component - `WelcomeComponent` in the place where `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` directive included in html.

As result we have injected Component in with it's own html and logic in some specific place.

Comment: Yep, the course gives that code sample but then says the router locates or creates. So if I don't have an object that matches an object, what does it mean by create? Does it mean it creates an empty object or does it create something more contextual, something that looks like a place holder? I'm trying to get past my own assumptions and find out what it creates if the option is not available.

Comment: if which options is not available ?

Comment: @itdnext, and what do you mean you don't have object that matches an object? I am a bit confused